# Typing performance in ckeditor4 on Chrome is low, input is lagging on large text in HTML editor

Tags: performance, google-chrome, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, html-editor

I have a project with ckeditor4 in it. I use 'wysiwygarea' plugin for fullscreen html editing. Locally everything seems fine but on testing environment Chrome input on large documents started lagging. The problem appears on Chromium engine only, FF seems to be working fine.
It appears like this: I open editor, start typing at the end of large document with tables and images, the speed is actually normal, but in 2-3 seconds it slows down and there's notable lag between keydowns and letters appearing. It started recently, Chrome v.89 does not seem to have this problem. If you spotted something similar in your projects, please share your thoughts

Comment: This problem could be caused by ckeditor reloading bunch of pics for document and icons for context menu after every text selection or right-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to CKEditor v.5+ was not available so my team decided to switch to another, lightweight editor.